# Move a list from one Trello board to another

Tags: trello

Is there a way to move a list from one Trello board to another?

I'm using Trello as a simple task-list system for development of an iOS product. I move my cards from "Todo" through "Working on" and finally to "Done". However, this process repeats itself for every release, so I would like to take the Done list and flush it out to another board, say "Past releases"

The list has a Move command, that that only moves it from one column to another in a given board. The same for cut and paste. It seems you can do this card-by-card, but that is not what I want.

I would have thought this would be easy, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* move the entire list to a different board. From the list’s *Move* command, you can choose the board you want it moved to. (In the second picture below, if you click on the board’s name, you get the list with all your boards.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ahhhh! That is very well hidden. I did not think those were buttons that popped up, so when I saw they listed the items in the same board, I simply closed.

Comment: Yeah, not exactly user friendly those drop-down lists.